# Redshift correlated subquery pattern is not supported

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to convert a timestamp into time but it does not work. it says

ERROR: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error.

this works:

```
,CAST(regdate as  timestamp) as "Date"
```

but if I do

```
,CAST(regdate as  time) as "Time"
```

it gives an error.

I tried also to do

```
CASt(CAST(regdate as  timestamp) as time)
```

but still the same error...

regdate is "timestamp without time zone)

any suggestion?

Comment: I suggest you post a complete query....

Comment: I tried to do a simpler query and it actually worked...but in the big query does not work...if I use timestamp works if I use time it does not...how is that possible? I am just changing that coulmn
The big query has a lot of joins so it is complicated

Comment: A "correlated subquery" error has nothing to do with your casting.  I suspect the error is coming and going because you are changing the name of the result between "date" and "time" (generally a bad idea to name columns the same as datatypes).   The name "time" is likely what is causing the correlated subquery error.  You will need to post the full query to get help on resolving this.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to extract the time part from the timestamp field, you can use the [TO_CHAR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_CHAR.html) function to achieve it

Use the Date Time format strings to achieve the way you want your result to look.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_FORMAT_strings.html

---

**Query #1**

```
select to_char(timestamp '2009-12-31 23:15:59', 'HH24:MI:SS');
```

| to_char |
| --- |
| 23:15:59 |

---